# LinkedIn integration with scribe

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, scribe

can someone help with linkedIn integration on backend.
Here is the trouble, i have oauth_token (which is already responsed with linkedIn javascript api), and i want to work with this token on backend.

Here is the example:

```
    OAuth20Service service = new ServiceBuilder()
        .apiKey(getLinkedInClientId())
        .scope("r_basicprofile r_emailaddress") // replace with desired scope
        .apiSecret(getLinkedInSecret())
        .build(LinkedInApi20.instance());

    try {
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = new OAuth2AccessToken(props.getToken(), "Bearer", 0, null, null, null);

        final OAuthRequest request = new OAuthRequest(Verb.GET, String.format("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~"),
            service);
        request.addHeader("x-li-format", "json");
        request.addHeader("Accept-Language", "ru-RU");
        service.signRequest(accessToken, request);
        final Response response = request.send();
        String body = response.getBody();
        response.getMessage();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It always said that i have invalid token.

```
{
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Invalid access token.",
  "requestId": "OKZVL3STZK",
  "status": 401,
  "timestamp": 1472554177625
}
```

Also i tried with Apache oltu client without luck (

It seems like i don't get valid token, because when i use https://apigee.com/console/linkedin everything is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token i used it wasn't access_token, so i've chosen to use OAuth2 for backend implementation.